# How do I set the width and height of a popup using QGIS2Web and Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

I am a newbie to editing javascript.

I want to set the Max width and height of the popup that QGIS2Web generates with a Leaflet map (I have quite a lot of text in the attributes and will need a scroll bar).

Could someone help me out with the code that I would need to insert in my index.html file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following CSS somewhere (either between <style> tags in your main map HTML file within the <head>, or better in a CSS file):

```
.leaflet-popup-content {
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[image]

Not fully tested - hope it's broadly correct.

Comment: That's brilliant @Tom, I dropped that into the header section as you suggested, increased the size of the popup to 300x300 and it is working perfectly. You can see the results at http://knowwhereconsulting.co.uk/WebMaps/Invincibles/index.html Thanks ever so much

Answer (score 2):

For even more specificity, edit the qgis2web.css file in the RESOURCES sub-directory created by the qgis2web plugin, as shown below. See the changes to height, width and overflow parameters.

[image]